# Array-style initialisation of the matrix class

Tags: c++, matrix, c++17

Suppose I want to create a matrix class in C++ which can be initialised using the curly brackets:

```
matrix<int> M = {{1,2,3}, {2,3,1}}
```

As I found out, the right hand side is an `std::initializer_list` object. I tried to implement the following:

```
template <typename ring>
class matrix {
private:
  std::vector<std::vector<ring>> vals;
public:
  matrix<ring>& operator=(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<ring>>& rhs);
};

template<typename ring>
matrix<ring>& matrix<ring>::operator=(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<ring>>& rhs) {
  unsigned new_rows = rhs.size();
  unsigned new_cols = 0;
  for (unsigned i=0; i<new_rows; ++i) if (new_cols < rhs[i].size()) new_cols = rhs[i].size();
  vals.resize(new_rows);
  for (unsigned i=0; i<vals.size(); ++i) {
    vals[i].resize(new_cols);
    for (unsigned j=0; j<new_cols; ++j) {
      vals[i][j] = rhs[i][j];
    }
  }
  return *this;
}
```

This does not work, and I get keeping the error message that rhs cannot accept the rhs[i][j] implementation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That seems like a lot of code for what should just be replacing the vector wholesale. Why the surgical precision?

Comment: When working with numerical linear algebra, it is realy worthy to create a separate class for matrices than adding additional methods and overloading operators for the vector class.

Comment: I get that part, I'm asking why you don't just wholesale stomp your local, like `vals = rhs.vals` and wash your hands of the details? All this code seems like it's just asking for messy off-by-one bugs.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in many libraries you have fixed-size matrixes, you can't just arbitrarily assign them. What starts life as a 4x4 will never change size. This means you can do really tight vector (math, not `std::vector`) optimizations using SIMD on them if they're of a specific size.

Comment: This seemed like a more elegant solution. But if an expert like you would say that the costs (=having bugs) outweighs the benefits (very readable code) then I would probably leave it as it is (i.e. initialising by passing the values to vals).

Comment: I'd challenge that assumption. Try benchmarking your code vs. doing the "dumb" version of just `vals = rhs.vals` and see how they perform. In an optimized build I think you'll be surprised. The `std::vector` code has been aggressively tuned, and I bet their memory copying code is better than yours.

Comment: That being said, if this was defined as a template with fixed constants for `W` and `H`, I bet you could just copy the memory over yourself using some simple copy calls into a 1D array that emulates your 2D structure. The more vectors you have here, the more chance you have for them to be non-contiguous in memory, destroying any performance gains this code has. If you can express it as *one* `std::vector`, that's almost always better than *N* of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
matrix<double> M = {{1,2,3}, {2,3,1}}
```

Is [*copy-list-initialisation*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). You need a constructor

```
matrix<ring>(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<ring>> rhs) : vals(rhs.begin(), rhs.end()) {}
```

I'd retain the assignment operator, but implement it using the constructor

```
matrix<ring>& matrix<ring>::operator=(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<ring>> rhs) {
    matrix temp = rhs;
    std::swap(vals, temp.vals);
    return *this;
}
```

Aside: `std::initializer_list` is already a type with const reference semantics, you may as well take it by value.